# Apache stops responding for some seconds

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, timeout

We have a website hosted on a VPS

Sometime the apache server stops responding for some seconds, the cpu goes to 0% and we get this page trying to load any page (instantly, it doesn't even try to load)

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zgu0.jpg)

After some seconds everything goes back online and we get a CPU/Ram usage spike because all the requests get processed at the same time

This happens randomly at any hour even in the night when i'm the only one on the website

We also have a blog on a subdomain and another small website hosted on this VPS on a completely different domain

What could be the cause of this? Our VPS provider isn't able to find the problem because it happens 1-2 times a day and only for 20-40 seconds

Thank you

Comment: Does the VPS lose network connectivity otherwise during these outages? or only apache stops serving requests?

Comment: @Joe the blog and the other domain stop responding too but i'm able to access the cpanel and the phpmyadmin interface, ssh access is working aswell

Comment: If you're still able to connect to the VPS and only apache is not responding, then it doesn't seem like an issue with the VPS provider. So let's narrow it down to apache.

The best advice I could give you is to look at the apache logs. On a cpanel server they are found at /usr/local/apache/logs/

When it's failing, you could also check the status of apache by running: `apachectl status`